# Return consecutive items or single items with null property from an array of objects as array of subsets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, data-structures

I'm looking for a solution on how to extract only consecutive objects with a null property from an array of objects, please see the example below.

**Important note:**

`Array.proptype.filter((item)=> item.y === null)` doesn't solve the problem here, `.filter` method will simply return an array objects where `y` is equal `null`.

What I'm willing to achieve here is actually quite more sophisticated than returning a simple array, the goal is to write a method that can iterate through each item in the array, check if the next item also has a null `y`, if true, the next item must be added to the extracted **subset** of objects.

Consecutive items are simply the items that come after each other, if the object with the index 3 has a null `y` property and the object with index 4 has a null `y` property as well, objects with indexes 3 and 4 can be considered as consecutive items,

If the item with index `8` has a null `y` but the items respectively with indexes `7` and `9` doesn't have a null `y`, only the item with index `8` must be added to the extracted subset.

---

***First use case:***

the method must be able to spot consecutive nulls and extract them as a subset of the original input set.

input:

```
['spider', null, null, null, 'cat','horse', 'eagle']
```

output:

```
[
 [null, null, null], <= one subset of nulls representing the nulls between 'spider' and 'cat'
]
```

---

***Second use case:***

The method must be able to consider single null items and also extract them into a single item subset array.

input:

```
['spider', null, null, null, 'cat', null, 'horse', 'eagle']
```

output:

```
[
 [null, null, null], <== first subset
 [null], <== second subset representing the null item between the 'cat' and 'horse'
]
```

Given the dataSet below, I want to extract the items where `y` property is `null`.

***output pattern***

```
[ 
  [first-subset-of-consecutive-nulls],
  [second-subset-of-consecutive-nulls],
  [....]
]
```

Please note that the expected output data structure is an array of **arrays** and not an array of objects.

---

Here's a more real-life dataSet example with the expected output.
The expected output should be an array of arrays that contain a subset of the dataSet where the `y` property is null and the objects are consecutive.

```
const dataSet = [
 {x: 'foo', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'bar', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'yo', y: null}, <=
 {x: 'random', y: null}, <=
 {x: 'lorem', y: null}, <=
 {x: 'ipsum', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'dolor', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'var', y: null}, <=
 {x: 'mit', y: null}, <=
 {x: 'oder', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'whatever', y: null}, <=
 {x: 'something', y: 'random-y'} 
];
 
// Method signature e.g extractSuccesiveNullBy(objectProp: string, from: Array<any>);

extractSuccessiveNullsBy('y', dataSet);
```

Expected output:

```
[
  [ {x: 'yo', y: null}, {x: 'random', y: null}, {x: 'lorem', y: null}],
  [ {x: 'var', y: null}, {x: 'mit', y: null}],
  [ {x: 'whatever', y: null]
]
```

Any proposal will be well appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The hash grouping approach can be applied:

```js
const dataSet = [{x: 'foo', y: 'random-y'},{x: 'bar', y: 'random-y'},{x: 'yo', y: null},{x: 'random', y: null},{x: 'lorem', y: null},{x: 'ipsum', y: 'random-y'},{x: 'dolor', y: 'random-y'},{x: 'var', y: null},{x: 'mit', y: null},{x: 'oder', y: 'random-y'},{x: 'whatever', y: null},{x: 'something', y: 'random-y'}];

let counter = 0;
const result = Object.values(dataSet.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if (obj.y !== null) {
        counter += 1;
        return acc;
    }

    acc[counter] = acc[counter] ? [...acc[counter], obj] : [obj];
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misunderstood, you can loop through the array and see if the previous data was null.

```
function extractSuccessiveNullsBy(array, objectProp) {
    let result = [];
    let previous = false;
    for (const data of array) {
        if (data[objectProp] === null) {
            if (previous) {
                result[result.length - 1].push(data);
            } else {
                result.push([data]);
            }
            previous = true;
        } else {
            previous = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const dataSet = [
 {x: 'foo', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'bar', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'yo', y: null}, // <=
 {x: 'random', y: null}, // <=
 {x: 'lorem', y: null}, // <=
 {x: 'ipsum', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'dolor', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'var', y: null}, // <=
 {x: 'mit', y: null}, // <=
 {x: 'oder', y: 'random-y'},
 {x: 'whatever', y: null}, // <=
 {x: 'something', y: 'random-y'} 
];
function extractSuccessiveNullsBy(array, objectProp) {
    let result = [];
    let previous = false;
    for (const data of array) {
        if (data[objectProp] === null) {
            if (previous) {
                result[result.length - 1].push(data);
            } else {
                result.push([data]);
            }
            previous = true;
        } else {
            previous = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(extractSuccessiveNullsBy(dataSet, "y"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```